# Why VOH > VIH and VOL < VIL?

Tags: digital-logic

Electrical characteristics of any IC include VOH, VOL, VIH, and VIL.
To interface any two ICs, VOH and VIH should be compatible.
I am not able to understand why VOH should be greater than VIH and why VOL should be less than VIL.
Kindly help me to understand this. I tried a lot but still not able to get it through.

Comment: Why do you write "I-C" while everyone else writes "IC"? *to interface any two I-C V-oh and V-ih should be compatible* **Why?** As long as the range of the input at least includes that of the output, there is no problem. Explain why you think they are "incompatible". Also: link to a datasheet of an IC which has this "issue".

Comment: sorry for that.i was expecting the answer instead of pointing grammatical errors@Bimpelrekkie

Comment: And I was expecting proper use of technical terminology. You increase your changes of getting a proper answer if you ask a proper and clear question.

Comment: am a student and i don't have enough knowledge so i posted here and for your kind information i apologized also.thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For digital signals to be sent successfully from one IC to another they must agree on what range of voltage levels represent a logic '1' or a logic '0'.

\$V_{IH}\$ and \$V_{IL}\$ are specifications of the input characteristics of the gate that receives the signal. Any input voltage **greater** than \$V_{IH}\$ is guaranteed to be recognized as a logic '1', and any input voltage **less** than \$V_{IL}\$ is guaranteed to be recognized as a logic '0'.

For the gate that is creating an output signal, \$V_{OH}\$ is the **lowest** voltage that it will ever provide when it wants to signal a logic '1' and \$V_{OL}\$ is the **highest** voltage that it will provide to signal a logic '0'.

So, for the two ICs to be compatible the voltage that one IC creates on its output for a logic '1' must **always** be at least as high as the voltage that the other IC needs to see to recognize a logic '1'. In other words, we require that \$V_{OH} > V_{IH}\$. Similarly, for the two ICs to successfully communicate a logic '0' we require that \$V_{OL} < V_{IL}\$.

Ideally, \$V_{OH} \gg V_{IH}\$ and \$V_{OL} \ll V_{IL}\$. The differences between the output voltages and the input voltages are called the **static noise margin** of the interface, and you would like the noise margin to be large so that the circuits would work reliably in the presence of noise.
$$SNM_H = V_{OH} - V_{IH}$$
$$SNM_L = V_{IL} - V_{OL}$$

Comment: The difference is called "noise margin".

Comment: @DaveTweed Thanks, I will edit to discuss noise margin.